# mod_rewrite subdomain redirect unless folder specified

Tags: mod-rewrite

How would I go about doing a mod_rewrite to redirect to a diffent subdomain ONLY if a specific folder is not specified? For example:

- test.example.com --> redirect.example.com
- test.example.com/~user/* -- no redirect
- test.example.com/dir/ --> redirect.example.com

So far I have

```
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =test.example.com [NC]
ReWriteRule ^ http://redirect.example.com [L,R]
```

not sure on what condition to use for the user directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another ReWriteCond that excludes the specific folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(~user|/.*)$
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.example.com [NC]
ReWriteRule ^$ http://redirect.example.com [L,R]
```

*And* you should remove the '=' in your other ReWriteCond.